# How to locate a point in a sorted array?

Tags: c#, sorting, binary-search

For example, I have a sorted array (grid points): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

And I try to locate the position of 3.3 . It is between element 3 and 4 and thus the result should be the index of element 3, which is 3. Any method to do it?

Comment: Because the array is sorted you could do a binary search. The trick here would be to `floor()` the number first.

Comment: Both Array and List<T> has BinarySearch method for that by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use default `BinarySearch` method of either `List<T>` or `Array`, but it's not immediatly obvious how to get index of closest element if no exact match is found. For that you need to do it like this:

```
var list = new float[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var idx = Array.BinarySearch(list, 3.3f);
if (idx < 0)
    idx = ~idx;
```

If no direct match is found, method returns negative number which, after applying ~ operator to, gives you the index of next item *larger* than what you search for. In your case that would be "4" and so index is "4". To get closest item *smaller* than what you search for - just substract 1 (beware index can become -1 then and so be outside the bounds of array). Note also that if target element is larger than all elements in array - it (after applying ~ operator) will return index outside the bounds of array (index equal to array length). Also note that array\list must be already sorted - those methods will not sort it for you.